# Quota Limits For You-Tube Data API V3?

Tags: youtube-api

The new Google Developers console shows the following limit for YouTube Data API v3:

**PER USER LIMIT  2 requests/second/user**

Whereas the old Google Developers console shows:

**2.0 units/second/user**

(i.e. one is requests per second, the other is units per second which are quite different).

From - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost - the Search request appears to have a cost of 200 units, if the latter case above is correct would this mean we can only make one of these requests every 100 seconds?

This does seem to tie in more closely with what we are experiencing which is regular occurrences of the following 403 forbidden error after paging through only a few results from a YouTube search:

```
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "youtube.quota",
"reason": "quotaExceeded",
"message": "Quota Exceeded"
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "Quota Exceeded"
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The new console is right on this point. It's request/sec.

But you may have been hitting daily quota limits.

Remember that in many cases, you can substitute a less costly call, such as [youtube.videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list), in place of the [youtube.search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method. For example, to search most popular videos instead of the [search.list call](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&order=viewCount&type=video&_h=1&), you can use the [videos.list call using the most popular chart](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&_h=2&).

Comment: That's strange then, I am sure I am not hitting daily quota limits as this 403 happens after making a handful of requests. Also increasing the PER USER LIMIT to a higher requests/second/user value seems to fix the problem. Both of these point towards the new console being incorrect don't they?

Answer (score 1):

you can contact youtube and apply for higher quota or pay for higher quota